# AWS iot core access from lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-iot

I want to create a thing or delete a thing on AWS iot core using a lambda function but I don't know why my lambda function does nothing when I used AWS iot sdk, is that network issue? Should I set up vpc or something ?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = "YYYY";
var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({endpoint: endpoint});
var iot = new AWS.Iot();

exports.handler = async(event) => {
    iot.listThings().on('success', function(response) {
        var things = response.data.things;
        console.log("test")
        var myThings = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
           if (things[i].thingName.includes("myThing")) {
               myThings[i]=things[i].thingName;
           }
        }
    })

    iot.createThing(thingParams).on('success', function(response) {
    //Thing Created!
  }).on('error', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).send();
};
```

Response:

```
null
```

Request ID:

```
"ccccc-fffff-eeee-rrrr-rrrrr"
```

Function logs:

```
START RequestId: ccccc-fffff-eeee-rrrr-rrrrr Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: ccccc-fffff-eeee-rrrr-rrrrr
REPORT RequestId: ccccc-fffff-eeee-rrrr-rrrrr: 29.75 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 88 MB
```

Comment: *AWS.config.region = "YYYY"; does not look right, is that what you have in your actual code?

Comment: no, I setup actual name of the region.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because you using method callback and promise together, try to use only the promise approach.
Whats happen in your code, that the lambda invocation ends before the `on('success')` calls

Replace:

```js
exports.handler = async(event) => {
   iot.listThings().on('success', function(response) {
        var things = response.data.things;
        console.log("test")
        var myThings = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
           if (things[i].thingName.includes("myThing")) {
               myThings[i]=things[i].thingName;
           }
        }
    })
};
```

With:

```js
exports.handler = (event) => new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    iot.listThings().on('success', function(response) {
        var things = response.data.things;
        console.log("test")
        var myThings = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
           if (things[i].thingName.includes("myThing")) {
               myThings[i]=things[i].thingName;
           }
        }
        resolve("Done")
    })
}
```

Or With:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    iot.listThings().on('success', function(response) {
        var things = response.data.things;
        console.log("test")
        var myThings = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
           if (things[i].thingName.includes("myThing")) {
               myThings[i]=things[i].thingName;
           }
        }
        callback("Done")
    })
}
```

By the way, disclosure there is a detailed blogpost in Lumigo, the company I worked for:
https://lumigo.io/blog/node-js-lambda-execution-leaks-a-practical-guide/?highlight=execution%20leak

Comment: Thank you for your response, I try them both but nothing change in my lambda. nothing execute in  iot.listThings() even no  console.log is printing and I wonder why? should I setup a network or VPC .

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve my problem with another way by using iot rest api
can any one help about authentication method of these APIs.
Curl -X DELETE https://MY_REGION.console.aws.amazon.com/iot/api/thing/test

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": "userNotLoggedIn",
        "message": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For you original question - your private subnet where lambda is running need to have NAT Gateway configured for egress traffic.

This is required because you are interacting IoT Core API in the public domain.